# jQuery broken? Bootstrap not working properly ON BOOTSTRAP SITE visiting with development machine only

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, twitter-bootstrap-3, inference

On the Bootstarp site discovered the dropdown example's not working. I thought the BS site was broken - it isn't. It is just on this machine. I am worried as I may be getting false negatives as I try to hack some jQuery together (I am NOT a skilled programmer.)

[The dropdown site. I presume it works for everyone else.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns-example)

[image]
This is how it looks BEFORE I click on anything.

I tired this on another machine and it worked just fine.

I have tried everything I can think of:
I have rebooted and NOT started Xampp,
I have cleared the chance,
I have tried the sites in Edge.

I emphasise it is ONLY on THIS Windows 10 machine.

Ideas greatly appreciated. I am beyond confused and fear some of my "damn it won't work" moments in jQuery could be false negatives.

Offering my first ever bounty as doing lots of jQuery and I often do mnot understand the results.

Comment: I have the same result, dropdown opened before clicking anywhere, and staying open.
I'm on a dev machine, too, but not using JQuery.

Comment: Note that this happen only on this specific example. Other examples on the page works as intended.

Comment: @KevinFONTAINE for me on the main machine the dropup works proper BUT https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns-headers also does not work IE it is pre-opened. More later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comment, the other dropdown examples on the page are working correctly.

There is a specific CSS rule on this one :

```
.bs-example>.dropdown>.dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    clear: left;
}
```

That make it stay open.
If you disable the `display: block` you get the dropdown working as normal.

I suppose that they did it for example purpose, but I have trouble to see the point of it.
Anyway, don't worry, the whole bootstrap is not broken.

That being said, I don't know why it is not like this on your *other* computers. Maybe are they using an older cached version ?

Comment: Grovel. Just went back to second machine and **voila** it is NOT working ... which means it IS just on the web site. Also I misunderstood you last comment.

Comment: Kevin thanks but I weep as I give you 50 of my low number of points. Mind you one thing makes me very happy - you seem to have a low score (336 really?) so giving you the 50 will be great for you. Thanks for all your hard work.

Comment: @BeNice Sorry to hear that, but thank you very much.
I hope this will help you get at ease with the framework.
I am often on client premise and can connect to my account, so my reputation build up slowly, but thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Bug here. what they did is perfectly alright. they implemented events for # for this part of their website and they have overridden the default implementation i guess. It works fine in my works. Copy the example and see it for yourself:

check this. directly copied from the bootstrap site: 
https://jsbin.com/lopohemahu/edit?html,output

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry don't think you understand. I was not saying that the code was wrong. Quite the contrary. I said it worked fine on the other machine but NOIT on this, my main machine. See the image.

Comment: If you ran this code in your own web project in your machine(not running the bootstrap website) and it failed, It could be a browser issue.

Comment: It was my browser (obviously!) visiting Bootstrap site and I am pretty sure it IS a browser issue.

Comment: Tazbir another grovel as your code worked fine and, along with @Kevin FONTAINE, we have the answer. It is a DELIBERATE thing on the web site. The question is really a) did the dropdown on the other machine really work or was I just STUPID or b) ... well I am at a loss. Thanks for the effort. I am afraid Kevin gets the bonus and answer as he was here first but thanks a million especially for doing that code snippet.